# How can I use the __builtin_expect in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I use the `__builtin_expect(::)` in Swift?

Does Swift still support this method?

I found the following definition in Dispatch, but I can't call it.

```
public func __builtin_expect(_: Int, _: Int) -> Int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Builtin.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift) in the Swift standard library defines

```
/// Optimizer hint that `x` is expected to be `true`.
@_transparent
@_semantics("fastpath")
public func _fastPath(_ x: Bool) -> Bool {
  return _branchHint(x, expected: true)
}

/// Optimizer hint that `x` is expected to be `false`.
@_transparent
@_semantics("slowpath")
public func _slowPath(_ x: Bool) -> Bool {
  return _branchHint(x, expected: false)
}
```

and these are documented in the [Standard Library Programmers Manual: Builtins](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StandardLibraryProgrammersManual.md#builtins):

> `_fastPath` returns its argument, wrapped in a Builtin.expect. This informs the optimizer that the vast majority of the time, the branch
>   will be taken (i.e. the then branch is “hot”).
>
> [...]
>
> `_slowPath` is the same as `_fastPath`, just with the branches swapped. Both are just wrappers around `_branchHint`, which is otherwise never
>   called directly.
>
> [...]
>
> NOTE: these are due for a rename and possibly a redesign. They
>   conflate multiple notions that don’t match the average standard
>   library programmer’s intuition.

See also [Does guard hint the optimiser that this is the unlikely branch](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-guard-hint-the-optimiser-that-this-is-the-unlikely-branch/10135) in the Swift forum.

However, these functions are not publicly exposed, and the leading underscore indicates that they are meant for library internal use only.  It *is* currently possible to use them in your code

```
if _fastPath(conditionExpectedToBeTrue) {
    // ...
}

if _slowPath(conditionExpectedToBeFalse) {
    // ...
}
```

but that is not guaranteed to work or to compile in the future.